# Expandable list with different childs

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am implementing the checkbox and radio buttons for the child view.I have inflated the different layout also.But the problem is i have used if and else statement for the view and always else statement is executed without visiting to the if statement.can anyone tell me what wrong am i doing here? I want to have a chceckbox for my child but always radioButton appears.

```
public class ExpandableListItem {
public static final int CHILD_TYPE_EDITTEXT = 0;
public static final int CHILD_TYPE_TEXT_FIELD = 1;
public static final int CHILD_TYPE_RADIO_BUTTON = 2;
public static final int CHILD_TYPE_CHECKBOX = 3;

private List<String> childLabels;
private String title;
private int selectionType;



public List<String> getChildLabels() {
    return childLabels;
}

public void setChildLabels(List<String> childLabels) {
    this.childLabels = childLabels;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public int getSelectionType() {
    return selectionType;
}

public void setSelectionType(int selectionType) {
    this.selectionType = selectionType;
}}
```

This is my Adapter:

```
  @Override
public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String childLabel = expandableListItemList.get(listPosition).getChildLabels().get(expandedListPosition);

    switch (expandableListItemList.get(listPosition).getSelectionType()) {

        case ExpandableListItem.CHILD_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkbox, null);
            ((CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkfor_Child)).setText(childLabel);

            break;

        case ExpandableListItem.CHILD_TYPE_EDITTEXT:
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.plaintext, null);
            break;

        case ExpandableListItem.CHILD_TYPE_RADIO_BUTTON:
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.radiobutton, null);
            ((RadioButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radiofor_child)).setText(childLabel);

            break;
        default:

        case ExpandableListItem.CHILD_TYPE_TEXT_FIELD:
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textbox, null);
            break;
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

This is in my Builder class inside on create:

```
 private ArrayList<ExpandableListItem> getchildExpandableListItem() {
    final ArrayList<ExpandableListItem> expandableListItemList = new ArrayList<>();

    ExpandableListItem expandableListItem = new ExpandableListItem();
    expandableListItem.setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("Heading"));
    List<String> childLabels = new ArrayList<>();
    childLabels = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("options");
    expandableListItem.setChildLabels(childLabels);
   if (expandableListItem.getSelectionType()== 2) {
        expandableListItem.setSelectionType(ExpandableListItem.CHILD_TYPE_CHECKBOX);
    } else {
        expandableListItem.setSelectionType(ExpandableListItem.CCHILD_TYPE_RADIO_BUTTON);
    }
    expandableListItemList.add(expandableListItem);

    return expandableListItemList;
}
```

I think assigning 2 in if statement so it is not executed and go to else statement.What can i do here??

Answer (score 0):

check

```
expandableListItem.getSelectionType()
```

this value i think it will not return 2 so that you receive everytime Radio buttons rather than check box so check that data where it will fall into your app

Happy Codding!!

Comment: yes it doesnot return 2.So what can do to get check box?

Comment: So in any how you will bring a a value which is belong "2"

Comment: I am tryiing to do this but cannot,Can you please help it out?

Comment: Dear when will you fetch SelectionType data?

Comment: I will fetch it when i am adding to child items

Comment: So at that time check is there any selection type available which belongs to "2"?

Comment: i think expandableListItem.getSelectionType()== 2 should give but why it is not?